# How many times was a Ruby gem installed via `gem install` or `gem update`

Tags: ruby, statistics, rubygems, gemcutter, rubyforge

I am trying to find out how many times a gem was installed via `gem install` or `gem update`.

For example, Watir 1.6.2:

- it was installed 97 times via gemcutter (http://gemcutter.org/gems/watir/versions/1.6.2)
- it is downloaded 4,027 times from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=104

I have been told that 4,027 does not include installs made via `gem install` or `gem update`. Is that information correct? If yes, where can I find the numbers for `gem install` and `gem update`? I have looked everywhere I could think of at rubyforge, but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, I hope to migrate all the download stats over to gemcutter... although we're going to have to do that carefully since there are about 50M rows.  That said, here's what I've got for watir-1.6.2 on RubyForge:

```
gforge=> select count(*) from gem_downloads where gem_name = 'watir-1.6.2.gem';
 count 
-------
 29169
(1 row)
```

Comment: I can't believe that the sysadmin of RubyForge answers this question with a SQL query showing the raw data and gets no upvotes for this. Duly corrected. BTW: Thanks for all those years of awesome service!

Comment: Thanks Tom. So the short answer is: `gem install` and `gem update` stats are not public at rubyforge, but it will be visible on gemcutter soon?

Comment: Heh, thanks Jorg!  Thanks to Zeljko for letting me know this question was up here.  Also, Zeljko, those rubyforge stats are pretty much just static now since all downloads are coming from gemcutter... but hopefully we can make those public soon by just glomming them into the gemcutter database.

Answer (score 1):

With gemcutter being the new canonical source for gems, you'll have better luck with these statistics in the future.  All future gem installs will go through gemcutter.  Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure the old rubyforge download numbers are just web downloads; they don't include `gem install` or `gem update` stats.

I'm not sure if the `gem install` stats exist in any shape or form from the old rubyforge platform, but the person to email would be [Tom Copeland](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I already contacted Tom, and as you can probably see he already answered. :)